# Fazer aparecer e desaparecer classe do html pelo js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma página de cadastro, e quando os dados são inseridos errados, aparece um `alert();` informando o erro, mas gostaria que ao invés de ser alert, fosse uma mensagem de erro logo abaixo dos campos. Eu coloquei um span com uma mensagem de erro e com a class `sr-only` do boostrap que faz o que eu escrevi ficar invisível, mas como utilizo o js para fazer a classe sumir? ficaria no lugar do alert que tá no echo.

```
HTML
<span id="cpf"></span>Cadastrar</button>
<span class="sr-only">Dados incorretos.</span>

PHP
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Alguém com esses dados já se cadastrou. Tente novamente.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
```

Comment: Se não vai usar um alerta seria melhor fazer diretamente no php, utilizando um `if` que coloca ou não a classe

Comment: Olá, poderia marcar a resposta como correta? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("ID_DO_ELEMENTO").classList.remove("NOME_DA_CLASSE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar ou remover classes direto pelo javascript você pode fazer o seguinte:

Para adicionar

```
document.getElementById("seu-id").classList.add("sua-classe");
```

Para remover

```
document.getElementById("seu-id").classList.remove("sua-classe");
```

Mais informações [neste link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando o JQuery, pode usar o seguinte código:

Para remover classe:

```
$( "seu-id" ).removeClass( "sua-classe" );
```

Para adicionar classe:

```
$( "seu-id" ).addClass( "sua-classe" );
```

Mais informações [Add Class](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) e [Remove Class](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)